# How to start Todoist app minimized to tray on startup

Tags: startup, autostart, startup-applications

What is the correct launch command for Todoist app along with the modifier to launch the app minimized to tray on system startup?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea and it turns out, there is no command to autostart in the taskbar. The way I am doing it now is to autostart it and then close it to the taskbar. One can probably automate that "closing". You can set the app to close to the tray by left-clicking the Todoist icon and then selecting "Stay running in tray". This is saved somewhere over the sessions.